# hide theme files for admin beneath root

Tags: theme-development, htaccess, security, user-access

The purpose is to give full admin rights, but not to the proprietary theme files.

Our website is on **/root/public_html/**

We want to move only the themefolder **/root/public_html/wp-content/themes/**
beneath the accessible files to
**/root/themes/**

All other files stay as before on **/root/public_html/**

Then with .htaccess rewrite, we want to make the whole site work as before.

Is this possible with Wordpress ? With other systems like Modx it is possible, and is even suggested to improve security.

thanks

Comment: When you say give full admin rights what do you mean? Are you talking about access rights to FTP/SSH users? I don't see how this is improving security, what's the concern being addressed?

Comment: Hi, by full admin rights, I mean FTP access to /root/public_html/, but no FTP access to /root/
The user has full backend administrator rights, but just not to the copyrighted "theme" part, which is "hidden" a level beneath his access level. So I want to make it  work with  .htaccess rewrite rule. A security benefit is that no hacked php can be injected in the theme folder.

Comment: If the goal is to prevent an FTP user from modifying the theme, why not ask about that? There are far better ways to do this than what you've suggested that don't involve moving it. It also sounds like you're violating the GPL.  Your proposed solution would be broken by someone uploading a PHP file that enables the theme editor UI, or a file browser plugin.